# Check if there is a value in the array which has more than 10 difference with other values

Tags: javascript

I want to check if there is a value in the array which has more than 10 difference with other values:

```js
console.log(check());

function check() {
    const array = [21, 21, 10];  
    return array.some((val, i, arr) => val > arr[0] + 10);
}
```

The above array should return `true` because there is at least one value in the array which has more than 10 difference, But as you see it returns `false`!!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could take the max and min value and check the difference.

```js
function check(array) {
    return Math.max(...array) - Math.min(...array) > 10;
}

console.log(check([21, 21, 10]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if any of the array items are bigger than the first item + 10, which is not true.

You can check every element with the minimum element though:

```js
console.log(check());

function check() {
    const array = [21, 21, 10];
    const min = Math.min(...array);
    return array.some(val => val > min + 10);
}
```